# JAVE (Java Audio Video Encoder) library exception only on Linux (CentOS 7)

Tags: java, linux, ffmpeg, mp3, jave

I'm using **JAVE (Java Audio Video Encoder)** library and the developed application is on windows. 
On windows the conversion of an `.mp3` file is working fine but when I deployed **on linux (CentOS 7) an exception** is thrown.

As I understand **JAVE** has also a wrapper around an `ffmpeg` executable.

Here is my code:

```
try {
        File source = new File(sourceFile);
        File target = new File(targetFile);

        final AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
        audio.setCodec("libmp3lame");
        audio.setBitRate(88000);
        audio.setChannels(2);
        audio.setSamplingRate(44100);   

        EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
        attrs.setFormat("mp3");
        attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);

        Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
        encoder.encode(source, target, attrs);
} catch (EncoderException ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

Exception:

```
...

Caused by: it.sauronsoftware.jave.EncoderException: Error while opening codec for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:926)
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:713)
    at com.hft2.ejb.util.Mp3JaveEncoder.encode(Mp3JaveEncoder.java:36)
    ... 206 more
```

## Update

Here is the official page: http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/

Full exception log: https://jpst.it/1678l

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What exception you getting ? logcat only shows caused by

Comment: Is it possible that your system doesn't define that codec?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I don't know. **JAVE** is a wrapper over `ffmpeg`; but should I define on linux server that used codec (`libmp3lame`)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You told it which codec to use explicitly. But does it actually have that codec installed? Depending on how implementation is done, it might be unable to differenciate between invalid codec parameters and missing a codec altogether.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Yes, the codec `libmp3lame` in included in JAVE library.

Comment: Show the full ffmpeg log.

Comment: @Lokesh I updated the post, with full exception log.

Comment: @Mulvya i don't have a `ffmpeg` log. Do you know how can I activate this in JAVE? Or where should be generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the `bitRate` value of the `audioAttributes` object from `88000` to `96000` based on **Sampling rates** documented on the following page: https://micropyramid.com/blog/understanding-audio-quality-bit-rate-sample-rate/

Using the value of: `96000` as bit rate resolved my issue on linux environment.
Very interesting that on windows worked fine with the value of `88000`.

Did some tests and here is the result:

```
Linux supported bitRate values: 128000, 96000, 64000, 56000, 32000;
Linux not supported bitRate values: 88000, 24000, 16000;
```

Thanks for support!